# Converting String to millis

Tags: java, date, time

**How to convert a String to Seconds?**

I want it to support an inifite amount of parts ("10m", "5s" are parts)

**For example:**

"10s" > 10

"10m5s" > 605

"1h1m1s" > 3661

**All types of data**

s > seconds

m > minutes

h > hours

d > days

w > weeks

M > months (Capitalized)

y > years

**EDIT:**

Tried some code, returning "34822861" when inputting "1s", where time is the String.

```
    Long mil = 0L;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D+").matcher(time);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group();
        Long numb = Long.parseLong(s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[0]);
        String type = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[1];
        switch(type){
        case "s":
            mil = mil + (numb);
        case "m":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60);
        case "h":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60);
        case "d":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24);
        case "w":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
        case "M":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        case "y":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well parse into the parts you have noted, and then add (using the right multiple.  How are you handling leap years?  Let's see some code.

Comment: Everyone is downvoting because I am new to java and I have no idea how to do this.. :( How would I split this in parts?

Comment: PUt your algorithm in place and try some code .. take your input string .. parse through leading numbers, get the letter and repeat.

Comment: I tried some code, but it failed. :(

Comment: Where are your `break` statements?!

Comment: Put break; after every mil = mil + ...;

Comment: @BammerbomTheKing No, the downvotes are not because you are new to Java. The downvotes are because you posted without bothering to search StackOverflow first.

Comment: Careful - You cannot convert months or years to milliseconds without knowing *which* months or years you are talking about. Not all months are 30 days, and not all years are 365 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making sure you use break after each case!

```
Long mil = 0L;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D+").matcher(time);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group();
        Long numb = Long.parseLong(s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[0]);
        String type = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")[1];
        switch(type){
        case "s":
            mil = mil + (numb); break;
        case "m":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60); break;
        case "h":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60); break;
        case "d":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24); break;
        case "w":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7); break;
        case "M":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30); break;
        case "y":
            mil = mil + (numb * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365); break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don’t reinvent the wheel.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a variety of string formats for date-time values. One such format is [Durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `T` divides the date portion from the time portion. For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

Each chunk is optional, such as `PT30M` for a half hour.

## Joda-Time

Both the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (bundled in Java 8) use ISO 8601 as their defaults for parsing and generating string representation of date-time values. This includes the `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` format.

Joda-Time offers three classes for working with a span of time: [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), and [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html). (Note that such terms are not standardized and are used differently in different contexts.)

## Search StackOverflow

Search Stackoverflow to find hundreds of answers on these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Put `break;` after every `mil = mil + ...;`